# Submitteremail doesn't seem to work PHP FormEmail

Tags: php, email, formmail

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with the PHP code that it is not sending copies to the form submitter. I have the following in my php file;

```
$submitter = $_POST['submitteremail'];
if ($submitter == '') $submitter = 'info@info.com';
if (strstr($submitter, "\n") || strlen($submitter) > 50) die("Begone, foul spammer.");
```

And then I have this `<input type="hidden" name="submitteremail" value="yes">` in the html for the form. And this for the email text box

```
<p><label>Email: <span class="style34">___</span></label> <input name="Email" type="text" id="submitteremail" size="51"/></p>
```

From everything I know, which admittedly isn't a lot, this should work. I only have a very basic knowledge of PHP, so please go easy on me in your replies.

Thank you from the bottom of my heart for any help any of you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing by the ID of the field `submitteremail` when you should be using the name `Email`

Although I still can't guarantee your email will get sent since you didn't include that portion of the code.

Comment: This is the only other code I have that involves submitteremail.- mail($adminemail, 'Form Submitted: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($messagetoadmin), 'From: '. $submitteremail);

if ($_POST['submitteremail'] == 'yes')
{
 mail($submitteremail, 'Form Submitted: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($messagetosubmitter), 'From: '. $adminemail);
}
if ($autoresponse != '')
{
 
 mail($submitteremail, 'Re: '. stripslashes($_POST['subject']), stripslashes($body), 'From: '. $adminemail);
} I made the change to name="submitteremail" and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

name is the field that populates the $_POST array so

```
name="Email"
```

should be

```
name="submitteremail"
```

OR

```
$submitter = $_POST['submitteremail'];
```

should be

```
$submitter = $_POST['Email'];
```

Comment: @ColinMorelli i was doing that at the same time as you :-)

Comment: Thank you. I made the change you suggested and it still isn't working. Everything is exactly as I posted above except that I now have name="submitteremail" in my html code. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.